# AVPlayerItem's canPlaySlowForward property never called

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayeritem

I'm trying to enable slow playback rate for a video I'm playing using `AVPlayerLayer`. To do so the documentation states it will enable `rate` in the range of 0.0 - 1.0 if the `AVPlayerItem` returns `true` for `canPlaySlowForward`. This property is readonly, so you need to subclass `AVPlayerItem` and override this property to accomplish this. I've done that, but the video still does not playing at a slow rate, it's always the 1.0 rate. It never even calls the `canPlaySlowForward` property. Why is this?

```
import AVFoundation

class SlowMoPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {

    override var canPlaySlowForward: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Playing the video:

```
let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("some-video", withExtension: "mp4")!)
let playerItem = SlowMoPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.rate = 0.5
player.muted = true

let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

The only other thing I do related to video/audio is prevent it from stopping background audio, via:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
}
```

The video file does not include an audio track but this was still necessary to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `rate` after calling `play()`. No need to subclass `AVPlayerItem`.

```
func playVideo() {
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SampleVideo", withExtension: "mp4")!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
    player.rate = 0.5
}
```